# IOS9 voip communication

Tags: ios, push-notification, sip, voip, sip-server

In iOS9 apple deprecated setKeepAliveTimeout and recommend `UIRemoteNotification` with VOIP Type available in PushKit for VOIP calling. Ok I can imagine that I will write server application for sending these notification.

1) But what-if i need periodically re-register to proxy server.

2) And what about sip-proxy? Does it mean, that all sip-proxies will need extension for sending these notifications to iOS Devices?

Comment: Ok, I think little bit more and proxy re-register is not needed any more because sip proxy will call through VOIP push notification but this mean that all proxy need the extension for APNS. If I am incorrect please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded answers to these questions here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49363

tl;dr
1) re-registering is not in iOS 10 no longer supported
2) generic sip-proxy app is also not available in iOS 10